# how to update Result folder of Catalyst after change in database

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have created one Catalyst application and I have created **Schema** and **Model** using below command

```
perl script/myapp_create.pl model TestDatabase DBIC::Schema MyApp::Schema::TestDatabase create=static dbi:mysql:db
```

After this command, Result directory contains the `Abc.pm` for table named `abc`.

Now I added one more table named `xyz` in my database `db`.
The issue, I am facing is ,how can I **update Result folder** so that now it contains `Xyz.pm` for `xyz` table also.

I want to use `create=static` only.

After executing above command again,the Result folder changes.
But Isn't there any other better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since static is the way to do it, you'll have to rerun this statement after each change in the database schema.

Thats why I usually put this command in a small shell script.